# CommonJS throw error also with dynamic imports (importing an ES Module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I need to use a script as a `prebuild` and it's not working because of module incompatibilities.

I have my script with `.mjs` extension: `script.mjs`

```js
import helper from './src/helpers/file-helpers.js';
console.log(helper)
```

and when I launch it (Node v18.16.0) `node script.mjs` this is the result:

```bash
import fs from 'fs/promises';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tried everything, also using dynamic `import('./src/helpers/file-helpers.js').then(default => console.log(default)` every time the same error occurs.

**Aside notes**: I can't add `type="module"` on the package.json because it will break my project. I also can't rename the file `file-helpers.js` into `.mjs`. Is there any solution to this? I thought that by wrapping everything on a dynamic import it should work, why is `fs/promises` giving such a hard time here?

Comment: With the info provided, I'm not able to re-produce.  Node v18.12.1

Comment: _Why_ can't you rename it to `.mjs`? (Or use `require` instead of `import`?)

Comment: @CherryDT  `.js` seems to work fine here, the OP just doesn't seem to have provided enough info to produce the error.

Comment: .js can only work with type=module but they said the rest of the project is not compatible with that setting

Comment: @CherryDT   I have a `script.mjs` that does an import to `file-helpers.js` that then has an `import` for `fs/promises`, and it works fine for me in node  v18.12.1  , like I said, I can't re-produce here, the OP maybe needs to show more..  ps:  `"type": "commonjs"` in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this workaround will work in your case, but it's worth a try. It should work tho.
First create a wrapper script with .js extension. Import the runScript function from your script.mjs file and then execute it. This way, the main script that uses ES6 module syntax remains an .mjs file, but you can use a .js file as the entry point.

```js
// wrapper.js
import { runScript } from './script.mjs'

runScript()
```

Then update your script.mjs to export the functionality you want to run,

```js
// script.mjs
import helper from './src/helpers/file-helpers.js'

export function runScript() {
  console.log(helper)
}
```

Then run the wrapper script in node and see if it works.